# How to validate a cron expression in Laravel?

Tags: php, cron

Is there any way to validate user created cron expressions in Laravel?

Answer (score 4):

Not out of the box but there is a wonderful [cron expression parser](https://github.com/dragonmantank/cron-expression/) written in PHP.

`composer require dragonmantank/cron-expression` to install

Then you'll need to create a custom rule with `php artisan make:rule Cron`

Now simply call `isValidExpression()` in the `passes()` method like so.

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return CronExpression::isValidExpression($value);
}
```

Don't forget the message

```php
public function message()
{
    return 'The :attribute field must be a valid cron expression.';
}
```

In order to use it you can pass an instance of the rule in your form requests

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'cron' => [new Cron],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In laravel 6 you don`t have to require any additional modules.

The simpliest way is to extend the Validator object in `AppServiceProvider` class:

```
public function boot() {
    //  ...

    Validator::extend('cron', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        return CronExpression::isValidExpression($value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the validation rule for Laravel 10:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Cron\CronExpression as Cron;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;

class CronExpression implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param \Closure(string): \Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        if (Cron::isValidExpression($value) === false) {
            $fail("The $attribute field is not a valid cron expression.");
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```php
use App\Rules\CronExpression;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'cron_expression' => [new CronExpression],
    ];
}
```